# Invoke Function through Case statements

Tags: shell

Will the below statements work? I am trying to invoke function through Case Statements.

```
#!/bin/bash

function exit
{
`...`
`...`
`...`}
function start
{
`...`
`...`
}

`Case $input in`

`-book) $(exit) ;;`
`-goal) $(start) ;;`
`*) break ;;`
`esac`
```

Is the syntax correct?

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to run them and see whether they have the desired effect.

Comment: It would be helpful if you pasted this in the format of a real shell script.  As the previous comment says, why not try it, and adjust the script if it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a function:

```
myfunc() {
    echo 'hi'
}
```

then you can invoke that function in a case statement without a capturing expression. You do it just like any other command:

```
case "$param" in
    expr) myfunc;;
    *) echo 'nope';;
esac
```

You need not use a capturing expression unless you mean it. In your case, what you have would attempt to execute the output of the function as a command itself:

```
$ double_down() {
>    echo 'ping google.com'
> }
$ $(double_down)
PING google.com (74.125.226.169): 56 data bytes
```

it's possible, but seems unlikely, that you really want this.